# Creating infinitely spawning enemies

Tags: c#, xna

Since this is just my second game, I'm still a little unsure of how to continually create and use new instances of objects.  I know in actionscript that there is a way to create a new instance of something without giving it a name and then loop through a list of some kind.  But I'm wondering what would be the best way to do this in c# using xna.  If anyone could provide a simple code example it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem with instantiating using the "new" keyword?

Comment: @Fantius I think he means putting it in a list to use later instead of assigning it to a specific variable.

Comment: I'm aware that you use "new" to create a new instance/allocate memory but since I'm used to creating just a few objects with names that I've given them, I'm not entirely sure how I would create and manage an infinite amount of objects.

Comment: Use the generic collection classes like List<T>, Dictionary<TKEY,TVAL>, HashSet<T>.  There are lots of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like the below:

```
// A sample enemy class
class Enemy
{
    public int EnemyStrength { get; set; }

    public Enemy(int strength)
    {
        EnemyStrength = strength;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // A List to hold all the enemies
        List<Enemy> Enemies = new List<Enemy>();

        // Create some enemies
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Enemies.Add(new Enemy(i));
        }

        // Display the strength of them all.
        foreach (Enemy enemy in Enemies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(enemy.EnemyStrength);
        }

    }
}
```

The important bit is Enemies.Add(new Enemy(i)) which instantiates and adds an enemy to the list without assigning it to a named variable - which I think is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about XNA specifically but there are a lot of collections in C# that could be used. Most interesting are the generic ones like [`List<MyObject>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) which provides a strongly typed list (ie no casting needed). Other options would be things like [Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx), [Dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) (if you wanted to give them some names but also wanted to be able to easily loop through them or if you need to be able to find a single instance by some key quickly).

There are a lot of others as well but these are some of the most common ones.

Sample code (assumes you have a class called enemy):

```
List<Enemy> myList = new List<Enemy>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
        myList.Add(new Enemy());
}
```

Obviously this doesn't produce infinite enemies but it shows how to add a bunch of new unnamed objects to a simple list.

You might use it something like this:

```
foreach (Enemy badguy in myList)
{
    badguy.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XNA provides an infinite game loop by invoking Update and Draw continually. As Chris said, keep your objects in a list and each time you need to add a new object, instantiate it in Update method. Then let Update and Draw methods to traverse the list and call each object's Update and Draw methods respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Using the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern is a good start, as it will conserve resources.